# Javascript new array prototype in new object constructor

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor, prototype

If I do:

```
Array.prototype.test = "test"
Array.prototype.t = function() {return "hello"}
```

Every new `Array` will have the property `test` and the method `t`.

How can I do the same without affecting all Arrays?

Like:

```
Names = function(arr){
  // Contacts constructor must be the same of Array 
  // but add the property test and the function t
}
z=new Names(["john","andrew"])
```

So that `z.test` will return `"test"` and `z.t()` will return `"hello"`?
(but `Array.test` and `Array.t` would stay `undefined`)

I explain better:

```js
Array.prototype.t="test";
Array.prototype.test = function(){ return "hello";}

z=new Array("john", "andrew")
console.log(z);
```

But this affects ALL arrays.
I want the same but with a new constructor Names that inherits Array constructor.

Comment: "`// Contacts constructor must be the same of Array `" this part is not clear. Do you mean `Names` instances should inherit `Array.prototype` as well?

Comment: I want a prototype that does not affect all arrays but only itself..
Array.prototype.test = "test"
Array.prototype.t = function() {return "hello"}
affects all arrays
I wish to do
Names.prototype.test = "test"
Names.prototype.t = function() {return "hello"}
where Names inherits everything else from Array prototype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
class Names extends Array {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
  }
}

Names.prototype.t = 'test';

let z = new Names("john", "andrew")
z.push('Amanda')

console.log(z.t)
console.log(z)
```

You can easily set it at `Names.prototype`

Comment: not what I intended to do.
I want the same effect of the Array.prototype example but affecting only Names and not all arrays.

Comment: @Zibri: Please have a look at my updated solution. `z` can access the push method just like Array and `z` can access `t` as you wanted. And it doesn't pollute `Array`, as you wanted

Comment: perfect! I was getting crazy!

Comment: the instructions I was searching for where the first lines

class Names extends Array {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
  }
}
THANKS!

Comment: @Zibri: Glad to help! I know that feeling :D

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just extend `Array`?

```
class Names extends Array {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.t = "test";
  }

  test() { return "hello" }
}

let z = new Names("john", "andrew")
```

Comment: Nope.. executing your example returns:
Names [t: "test"]
instead of ["john","andrew"]

Comment: @Zibri Sorry, my bad, I actually forgot to pass the arguments to super

Answer (score 1):

Here is a crude implementation:

```js
function Names(arr) {
  this.contacts = enhanceArray(arr);
}

function enhanceArray(arr) {
  arr.test = 'helloProp';
  arr.t = function() {
    return 'helloFunc'
  }
  return arr;
}
let z = new Names(["john", "andrew"]);

console.log(z.contacts[0]);
console.log(z.contacts.test);
console.log(z.contacts.t());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own extended Array constructor factory, something like

```js
(() => {
  const myArr = XArray();
  let a = myArr(["John", "Mary", "Michael"]);
  console.log(`myArr(["John", "Mary", "Michael"]).sayHi(1): ${a.sayHi(1)}`);
  console.log("demo: myArr(1, 2, 3) throws an error");
  let b = myArr(1, 2, 3); // throws
  
  // an extended array
  function XArray() {
    const Arr = function(arr) {
      if (arr.constructor !== Array) {
        throw new TypeError("Expected an array");
      }
      this.arr = arr;
    };
    Arr.prototype = {
      sayHi: function (i) { return `hi ${this.arr[i]}`; }
    };
    return arr => new Arr(arr);
  }
})();
```

Comment: could you check your code, it seems there is a problem when executing. ;)

Comment: @Ivan that's by design ;P

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't pay enough attention!

Comment: No worries, the answer was evidently not clear enough. Edited it a bit.